# How to use "OR" in awk?

Tags: awk

I am trying add OR operator in awk command. The following does not work.

```
# echo "* * * * * ls >> abc.txt 2>> abc.err" | awk -F'2>>' or -F'>>' '{print $2}' 
awk: cmd. line:1: or
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: You should mention in title _what_ you want to OR (field separator?) and also post the wanted result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question:

```
$ echo "* * * * * ls >> abc.txt 2>> abc.err" | awk -F'2>>|>>' '{print $2}'
abc.txt
```

Comment: Could also write `-F '2?>>'` here